# 'kotlinx.serialization.json.Json'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies

Tags: json, kotlin, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

I am trying to use `kotlinx.serialization` in my KMM application to parse a `json` Http response from a website. I have tried many of the solutions that I have found on the web but non have solved my problem. I had to update to Android Studio/Kotlin Version 1.5.20 to eliminate an error in the Kotlin-datetime module. Know facing new compiler errors. Can anyone help?

Kotlin class:

```html
import com.pagetyler.dailynasa.shared.entity.Defaults
import io.ktor.client.*
import io.ktor.client.features.json.*
import io.ktor.client.features.json.serializer.*
import io.ktor.client.request.*



class NasaPicsApi {
    private val httpClient = HttpClient {
        install(JsonFeature) {
            val json = kotlinx.serialization.json.Json { ignoreUnknownKeys = true }
            serializer = KotlinxSerializer(json)
        }
    }

    suspend fun getPicture(currDate:String): List<NasaPicture> {
        val ep = "$PICTURES_ENDPOINT$EXTENSION?api_key=$DEFAULT_APIKEY;date=$currDate  "
        return httpClient.get(ep)
    }

    companion object {
        private val PICTURES_ENDPOINT = Defaults().PICTURES_ENDPOINT
        private val EXTENSION = Defaults().EXTENSION
        private val DEFAULT_APIKEY = Defaults().DEFAULT_APIKEY
    }
}
```

Common/Shared build.gradle.kts:

```js
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinNativeTarget
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

val kotlinVersion = "${rootProject.extra["kotlin_version"]}"
plugins {

    kotlin("multiplatform")
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version  "1.5.20"
    id("com.android.library")
    id("com.squareup.sqldelight")

}

group = "com.pagetyler"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    gradlePluginPortal()
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven(url = "https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlinx/") // soon will be just jcenter()
}


kotlin {
    tasks.withType<KotlinCompile>().configureEach {
        kotlinOptions {
            useIR = true
        }
    }
    val iOSTarget: (String, KotlinNativeTarget.() -> Unit) -> KotlinNativeTarget =
        if (System.getenv("SDK_NAME")?.startsWith("iphoneos") == true)
            ::iosArm64
        else
            ::iosX64

    iOSTarget("ios") {
        binaries {
            framework {
                baseName = "shared"
            }
        }
    }
    jvm().compilations.all {
        kotlinOptions {
            useIR = true
        }
    }

    android()

    val ktorVersion = "1.4.0"
    val serializationVersion = "1.0.0-RC-$kotlinVersion"
    val sqlDelightVersion: String by project
    val coroutinesVersion = "1.3.9-native-mt"

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutinesVersion")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-datetime:0.2.1")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-core:$serializationVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization:$ktorVersion")
                implementation(kotlin("stdlib-common"))
                implementation("com.squareup.sqldelight:runtime:$sqlDelightVersion")
                //implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlinVersion")

            }
        }
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-common"))
                implementation(kotlin("test-annotations-common"))
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-datetime:0.2.1")
                //implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-core:$serializationVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-android:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("com.squareup.sqldelight:android-driver:$sqlDelightVersion")
            }
        }
        val androidTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-junit"))
                implementation("junit:junit:4.13")
            }
        }
        val iosMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-ios:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("com.squareup.sqldelight:native-driver:$sqlDelightVersion")
            }
        }
        val iosTest by getting
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion(30)
    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion(24)
        targetSdkVersion(30)
        versionCode = 2
        versionName = "2.0"
        
    }
    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
        }
    }
}

sqldelight {
    database("PicturesDB") {
        packageName = "com.pagetyler.shared.cache"
    }
}

val packForXcode by tasks.creating(Sync::class) {
    group = "build"
    val mode = System.getenv("CONFIGURATION") ?: "DEBUG"
    val framework = kotlin.targets.getByName<KotlinNativeTarget> 
("ios").binaries.getFramework(mode)
    inputs.property("mode", mode)
    dependsOn(framework.linkTask)
    val targetDir = File(buildDir, "xcode-frameworks")
    from({ framework.outputDirectory })
    into(targetDir)
}

tasks.getByName("build").dependsOn(packForXcode)
```

This is the Global build.gradle.kts

```js
buildscript {


val kotlin_version by extra("1.5.20")
repositories {
    gradlePluginPortal()
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven(url = "https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlinx/") // soon will be just jcenter()
}

val sqlDelightVersion= "1.5.0"

dependencies {
    classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2")
    classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.0")
    classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-serialization:$kotlin_version")
    classpath("com.squareup.sqldelight:gradle-plugin:$sqlDelightVersion")

    file("libs\\YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jarlibs\\YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar")
}
}
apply (plugin = "com.squareup.sqldelight")
apply (plugin = "kotlin")



group = "com.pagetyler"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven(url = "https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlinx/") // soon will be just jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe `org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-core` and `io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization` are clashing? Just a guess though.

Comment: Tried removing `io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization` but creates more errors. Restored it and Upgraded to gradle-6.8.2 and now get same IDE errors but build completes with no errors.

Comment: Only guess is removing the other one, but again just a guess

Comment: check the dependency tree for clashing jars with different versions

Comment: The only thing that I have found that may be a clash is with the `classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-serialization:$kotlin_version")` in the project Gradle file and the `implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-core:$serializationVersion")` in the shared file. My Kotlin version is "1.5.20" and my serialization core version is "1.0.0-RC". I tried changing these to use the same version it breaks one or the other.

Comment: I have also ran a Gradle scan on the project but all I get is the same message that I get from my build. I am not that grate at Gradle here is a link  to the scan **[link](https://gradle.com/s/rpouqlibvo2t2/activate/lcujvnst6fa4q)** Maybe there is something that I am missing in it.

Comment: So all I did was change the order of the `ktor` and `kotlinx-serialization` implementations like this `implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktorVersion")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization:$ktorVersion")
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-core:$serializationVersion")` this is more clear but I don't see the conflict. New message is `Error: Dependencies using groupId com.android.support and androidx.* can not be combined but found com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.0 and androidx.databinding:databinding-adapters:4.2.2 incompatible dependencies`

Comment: Not enough room to make the comment clear above. By resequencing the implementations I now get the new message. I am going research this new error now.

Comment: Upgraded to Artic Fox 2020.3.1 and all this craziness has went away. Not sure if I solved my problem or just hid it for now. I will try running some test.

Answer (score 0):

This issue appears to be unique to Android Studio 4.2.2 Beta 5. I did not have it before I migrated to it. The problem went away when I migrated to the next release of Artic Fox 2020.3.1.

Avoid using `Android Studio 4.2.2 Build #AI-202.7660.26.42.7486908, built on June 23, 2021` if you can.